# hover image over another image

Tags: css, hover, fading

I am confused with soemthing most likely quite simple, but I can't figure it out. I want Image 2 to cover Image 1 when I hover over Image 1.
So, the goal is to overlap Image 1 with an Image 2 containing a semi-transparent color gradient. I know this could somehow be achieved with pure CSS, but I need it this way.

The below CSS Code was taken from another Typo3 CMS Website and there it works.

However, I can't seem to make it work on another part/element of that Typo3 website, I even can't make it work on a simple basic HTML page like this one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>

.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}

img {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container .hover-second-image-over-first-image:hover {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image:url(image_02.jpg);
  background-position:top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100%;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
 <div class="hover-second-image-over-first-image"></div>
 <img src="image_01.jpg" />
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Edit:

Ok, so "z-index:10;" did fix it for me. This code here works:

```
.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}

img {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container .hover-second-image-over-first-image {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image:url(image_02.jpg);
  background-position:top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100%;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:10;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.container:hover .hover-second-image-over-first-image {
  opacity:.3;
}
```

But I still wonder why the code worked before on that other website WITHOUT any z-index position...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to keep attention here :

- Don't put your styles inside the `<body>` tag
- Try to style the layer you want to see over the image whitout the use of the `:hover` state so it must be `.container .hover-second-image-over-first-image`
- Use the `:hover` action on all the `.container` element

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .hover-second-image-over-first-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background:blue;
  opacity:0;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:10;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.container:hover .hover-second-image-over-first-image {
  opacity:.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hover-second-image-over-first-image"></div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but my problem still persists. This CSS Code here works in the Typo3 Website: .container .hover-second-image-over-first-image:hover {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image:url(image_02.jpg);
  background-position:top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100%;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}   And I have no idea, how/why it works :))

Comment: Your code does work, but you removed the image and you did alter the code. My problem is that the CSS code as you see in my posting is the original code taken from the website, and I just don't get how the heck it works :)